# IcoMoon App icon fonts are shown as 

Tags: css, fonts, icons

Everything is fine but when I use ../ it doesn't work. To call the CSS I use: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../IcoMoon-App/style.css" />` and it do appears but as . I get the error at `MainFolder/Albumes/Clarity_Deluxe_Edition/index.html`, but when use the icons at `MainFolder/index.html` they're displayed well (note that the css location to this one is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="IcoMoon-App/style.css" />`).  This is how my directory is structured:

```
MainFolder
├index.html
├css
│└index_style.css
├IcoMoon-App
│├IcoMoon-App.eot
│├IcoMoon-App.svg
│├IcoMoon-App.ttf
│├IcoMoon-App.woff
│└style.css
└Albumes
 └Clarity_Deluxe_Edition
  ├index.html
  └css
   └index_style.css
```

Yes, because of I changed the location, I also changed the @font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'IcoMoon-App';
    src:url('IcoMoon-App.eot?xzz47n');
    src:url('IcoMoon-App.eot?#iefixxzz47n') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('IcoMoon-App.woff?xzz47n') format('woff'),
        url('IcoMoon-App.ttf?xzz47n') format('truetype'),
        url('IcoMoon-App.svg?xzz47n#IcoMoon-App') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Am I using wrong the "back folder" (../, don't know the exact name)? Or I did a mistake when changing the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this is using a different way of defining your paths.

In your CSS file, change the path to your IcoMoon font files to:

`src:url('/IcoMoon-App/IcoMoon-App.eot?xzz47n');`

The `/` at the very start of the URL makes the browser start from the domain-level of your website and then add the URL exactly as it appears in the example I gave. This will build an "absolute" URL to your IcoMoon font files, regardless of how deep in your folder structure you are.

A drawback to this approach is that the fonts may not appear when you're browsing your site locally (e.g. at `http://localhost/~alej27/yoursite`) because that would make the browser search for the font files at `http://localhost/IcoMoon-App/IcoMoon-App.eot?xzz47n`. There are ways around that (hosts file modifying and setting up a virtual domain) but that's outside the scope of this question :)

Comment: Even when I used `/` it didn't work neither, but I guess it's because of I'm using a local host.

Comment: What is the full URL of your website when you're developing on your computer?

Comment: My website isn't online, I'm just working on it local (with my computer).

Comment: So when you open your website in the browser on your computer, what is the full URL? Does it start with `c:\Users\` or ` http://localhost`? :)

Comment: It's `file:///C:/Users/Alejandro/Desktop/Webs/Tervon/Albumes/Clarity_Deluxe_Edition/index.html#`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly why using `/` didn't work - it's basically because you're opening the HTML file as just that: a file, rather than having a webserver deliver it to your browser and that affects how the browser interprets the `/` :)  I would advise you to enable IIS (Internet Information Services) on your computer: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-turn-on-iis-internet-information-services for Windows 8, and http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2010/05/04/enabling-iis-on-windows-7/ for Windows 7.  
When that is done, you'll go and create a virtual directory to point to your website.

Comment: When you've got IIS running, here's a guide to creating a virtual director (or web application): http://www.helpmasterpro.com/helpfile/Web%20Modules/html%20files/Virtual%20Directory%20-%20creating%20in%20iis7.htm  
This way you will be able to get to your website through a URL, e.g. http://localhost/ClarityDeluxe - good luck! :)